# How to update the selected options dynamically in ng multi-select drop-down

Tags: angular

I have the two multi- select drop-down states and regions, I am selecting multiple values for states and according to that region drop-down data is updating and i am selecting region according to that.

when i am deselecting any state that time selected region from that state is not deselecting.

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown #multiSelect [placeholder]="'Select State'" [data]="states" [settings]="settings" formControlName="state" class="multiselect-dropdown-list" (onSelect)="getRegions($event)"></ng-multiselect-dropdown>




<ng-multiselect-dropdown #multiSelect [placeholder]="'Select Region'" [data]="regions" [settings]="settings" formControlName="region" class="multiselect-dropdown-list" ></ng-multiselect-dropdown>


getStates(){
  get states api
  states array
}

getRegions(event){
   get region api
   regions array
}
```

Comment: Can't help if you don't share your code. Preferably upload to Stackblitz. Regardless, you are reusing the same ref name `#multiSelect` and the same `formControlName="state"` in both elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.getCategoryGroupList();
        this.getCategoryDetails();
        // console.log(this.configurableProductService.configProductCategoryForm.value);
    }
    getCategoryDetails() {
        this.configurableProductService.getConfigurableProductCategorydetails(this.params.id).subscribe((response: any) => {
            if((response !== null) && (response.data[0].productId === this.params.id)) {
                let categoryIds = response.data.map((data)=> data.categoryId);
                let subCatIds = response.data.map((data)=> data.subCategoryId);
                
                if (response.data[0].categoryGroupId) {
                    this.onSelectCategoryGroup(response.data[0].categoryGroupId, categoryIds);
                }
                
                if (response.data[0].categoryId) {
                    
                    this.onSelectCategory(response.data[0].categoryId, subCatIds, categoryIds);
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    formInitialization(data?: ProductCatalogueModel) {
    // this.productRule = PRODUCT_CATELOGUE_RULE();
    this.categoryDetail = data;
    
    this.configProductCategoryForm = this.fb.group({
      'categoryGroupId': [data ? data.categoryGroupId : '', [Validators.required]],
      'categoryId': [data ? data.categoryId : '', [Validators.required]],
      'subCategoryId': [data ? data.subCategoryId : '', [Validators.required]],
    });
    // this.onChanges();
    // this.updateTabStatus();
  }

    // Fetch Category Group List.
    getCategoryGroupList() {
        this.configurableProductService.getAllCategoryGroupList().subscribe((response: any) => {
            if (response) {
                
                const categoryGroup = filter(response.data, { isActive: 1 });
                this.categoryGroupList = categoryGroup;
            }
        }, (error: any) => {
            if (error.status === API_STATUS_CODE.badRequest) {
                this.notify.error(error.error.data);
            }
        });
    }
    

    // On Selecting Category Group Fetch Category List.
    onSelectCategoryGroup(value: number, categoryIds: any, from?: boolean) {
        if (from) {
            this.categoryList = null;
            this.subCategoryList = null;
            this.configurableProductService.configProductCategoryForm.controls['categoryId'].setValue([]);
            this.configurableProductService.configProductCategoryForm.controls['subCategoryId'].setValue([]);
        }
        this.configurableProductService.getCategoryByCategoryGroupId(value).subscribe((response: any) => {
            if (response) {         
                if (categoryIds) {
                    this.configurableProductService.configProductCategoryForm.controls['categoryId'].setValue(categoryIds);
                }
                const category = filter(response.data, { isActive: 1 });
                this.categoryList = category;
            }
        }, (error: any) => {
            if (error.status === API_STATUS_CODE.badRequest) {
                this.notify.error(error.error.data);
            }
        });
    }

    // On Selecting Category Fetch Sub Category.
    onSelectCategory(value: number, subCatIds: any, categoryIds: any, from?: boolean) {
        if(categoryIds){
            const unique = (value, index, self) => {
                        return self.indexOf(value) === index
            }
            const uniqueIds = categoryIds.filter(unique)
            value = uniqueIds;
        }
        if (from) {
            this.subCategoryList = null;
            this.configurableProductService.configProductCategoryForm.controls['subCategoryId'].setValue([]);
        }
        this.configurableProductService.getSubCategoryByCategoryId(value).subscribe((response: any) => {
            if (response) {
                if (subCatIds) {
                    this.configurableProductService.configProductCategoryForm.controls['subCategoryId'].setValue(subCatIds);
                }
                const subCategory = filter(response.data, { isActive: 1 });
                this.subCategoryList = subCategory;
            }
        }, (error: any) => {
            if (error.status === API_STATUS_CODE.badRequest) {
                this.notify.error(error.error.data);
            }
        });
    }
```

```
    <form class="col s12" [formGroup]="configurableProductService.configProductCategoryForm">
                <div class="col s4">
                    <app-mat-select-search  (selectionChange)="onSelectCategoryGroup($event.value, false, true)"
                        [label]="'CATEGORY_GROUP_ID' | translate: lang" [list]="categoryGroupList" valueField="categoryGroupId"
                        [myFormControl]="configurableProductService.configProductCategoryForm.controls['categoryGroupId']"
                        [requiredMsg]="'REQUIRED' | translate:lang"
                        [searchPlaceholder]="'CATEGORY_GROUP_SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER' | translate: lang" [isInactive]="true"
                        [isRequired]="true" [noResultsLabel]="'CATEGORY_GROUP_SEARCH_NOT_FOUND' | translate: lang"
                        displayField="categoryGroupName">
                    </app-mat-select-search>
                </div>
                <div class="col s4">
                    <app-mat-select-search multiple (selectionChange)="onSelectCategory($event.value,  false, false, true)"
                        [label]="'CATEGORY_ID' | translate: lang"  [list]="categoryList" valueField="categoryId"
                        [myFormControl]="configurableProductService.configProductCategoryForm.controls['categoryId']"
                        [requiredMsg]="'REQUIRED' | translate:lang"
                        [searchPlaceholder]="'CATEGORY_SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER' | translate: lang" [isInactive]="true" [isRequired]="true"
                        [noResultsLabel]="'CATEGORY_SEARCH_NOT_FOUND' | translate: lang" displayField="categoryName">
                    </app-mat-select-search>
                </div>
                <div class="col s4">
                    <app-mat-select-search  multiple [label]="'SUB_CATEGORY_ID' | translate: lang" [list]="subCategoryList"
                        valueField="subCategoryId"
                        [myFormControl]="configurableProductService.configProductCategoryForm.controls['subCategoryId']"
                        [requiredMsg]="'REQUIRED' | translate:lang"
                        [searchPlaceholder]="'SUB_CATEGORY_GROUP_SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER' | translate: lang" [isInactive]="true"
                        [isRequired]="true" [noResultsLabel]="'SUB_CATEGORY_GROUP_SEARCH_NOT_FOUND' | translate: lang"
                        displayField="subCategoryName">
                    </app-mat-select-search>
                </div>
            </form>
```